# Comparing strings with regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I basically want to match strings like: "something", "some,thing", "some,one,thing", but I want to not match expressions like: ',thing', '_thing,' , 'some_thing'.

The pattern I want to match is: A string beginning with only letters and the rest of the body can be a comma, space or letters.

Here's what I did:

```
import re
x=re.compile('^[a-zA-z][a-zA-z, ]*') #there's space in the 2nd expression here
stri='some_thing'
x.match(str)
```

It gives me:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='some'>
```

The thing is, my regex somehow works but, it actually extracts the parts of the string that do match, but I want to compare the entire string with the regular expression pattern and return False if it does not match the pattern. How do I do this?

Comment: Try `'^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z, ]*$'` or `'^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[ ,]+[a-zA-Z]+)*$'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `[a-Z]` which matches [more thank you think](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret).

If you want to match `[a-zA-Z]` for both you might use the case insensitive flag:

```
import re
x=re.compile('^[a-z][a-z, ]*$', re.IGNORECASE)
stri='some,thing'

if x.match(stri):
    print ("Match")
else:
    print ("No match")
```

[Test](http://rextester.com/ETOS27231)

Comment: I can't believe that wasted my 2 precious hours, I tested so much of patterns, and all was at fault was a simple case error. Thanks mate, that saved my life!!

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way would be to just compare the result to the original string.

```
import re
x=re.compile('^[a-zA-z][a-zA-z, ]*')
str='some_thing'
x.match(str).group(0) == str #-> False

str = 'some thing'
x.match(str).group(0) == str #-> True
```

Comment: the problem is that, the string will be compared from user input, and that can be arbitrary length. So can't compare with fix strings